# How to rewrite a file and move non-maching line above. Regex

Tags: regex, powershell, awk, sed

I have a text file with lines in a format like that:

```
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada dad","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada xxx","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada ttt","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad
dada ddd","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"
```

The line should always begin with `"\\server\...` and end with `,"submitted"`
however as you can see sometimes the line is divided and starts OK but part of the line is moved to a new line.

I need to rewrite the file to a new one with the the proper format.
Basically if the line doesn't start with the `"\\server.."` then it should be added to a previous line.
I need help with this - I can run the tool on Windows (powershell) or Linux (awk,sed).
Thank you in advance

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people here don't like that.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Making your question as easy to answer as possible means providing an [mcve]. In particular, please include the regex that you have now, and some examples of what it is matching incorrectly, or failing to match correctly.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. I tried the solution proposed by @mklement0 as the first one and it did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PowerShell solution using the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch):

```
& { 
  switch -wildcard -file in.txt { 
    '"\\server*"' { $_; continue } 
    '"\\server*'  { $prev = $_; continue } 
    default       { $prev + $_ }
  }
} | Set-Content out.txt
```

- Wildcard expression `"\\server*"` matches a self-contained line, inferred from the line ending in `"` - that line is output instantly (`$_`), and processing continues with the next line (`continue`).
- Wildcard expression `"\\server*`, by process of elimination, then matches an *incomplete* line, whose content is saved in variable `$prev` before moving on to the next line.
- Default handler `default` is then only processed for the lines that follow - and complete - incomplete lines, and string concatenation `$prev + $_` outputs the two lines stitched together.

Note that `Set-Content` by default uses the character encoding implied by the system's active ANSI code page in Windows PowerShell, and UTF-8 without BOM in PowerShell *Core*; use the `-Encoding` parameter to select a different encoding.

Comment: This is Godly. I mean truly I dont know how you came across that concept of switch with -wildcard. +1

Comment: Thanks, @RanadipDutta. Yes, `switch` is a powerful statement, and its capabilities aren't widely known, perhaps because similar statements in other languages have fewer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` command that saves the current line in `p` if the line does not end with `,"submitted"`, and print the line preceded with `p` if the line does start with it:

```
awk '{if(/,"submitted"$/){print p?p" "$0:$0;p=""}else{p=$0}}' file
```

Comment: Sure. Updated as suggested then.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows I bet the line breaks in the middle are just `\n`s while the line ends are `\r\n`s like you'd get if you exported a CSV from Excel where some cells contained line breaks, e.g.:

```
$ cat -v file
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada dad","submitted"^M
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada xxx","submitted"^M
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada ttt","submitted"^M
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"^M
"\\server\folder\file name dad
dada ddd","submitted"^M
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"^M
```

in which case all you need is (using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT):

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada dad","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada xxx","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada ttt","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada ddd","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"
```

otherwise you probably just need:

```
$ awk -v RS='"\r?\n' '{ORS=RT;$1=$1}1' file
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada dad","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada xxx","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada ttt","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada ddd","submitted"
"\\server\folder\file name dad dada rrr","submitted"
```